# How do I open wordpad using java

Tags: java

I am doing a small project for my girlfriends grandparents, that have a hard time using a computer so I thought I would be able to write something that might fix their problem. Here is the code first off:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenWordPad {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Opening WordPad");
        Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runTime.exec("wordpad");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Closing WordPad");
        process.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

(had to indent some so sorry if it is a little wonky)

When I put notepad in the process line it works fine but when I put in wordpad it freaks out. I want to be able to open wordpad so I can put it on their computer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Either specify full path to Wordpad or put Wordpad to the PATH variable on your girlfriends grandparent's computer.

Comment: How would I specify the full path?

Comment: On my system it would be "C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe". It works with Notepad because the directory is in the PATH environment variable (I guess, have not checked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use `runTime.exec("write")`:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenWordPad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Opening WordPad");
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec("write"); // <--- here
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Closing WordPad");
            process.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

opens WordPad.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! You will get the check-mark in 3 min! (when I can)